# Trying to upload metadata in json format to storage blob using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

Below is the code,

```
connection_string=';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_name = "ringr-dev/source_metadata"
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob="123.json")
Body=json.dumps(twilioMetadata)
with open(Body, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

Error,

```
No file found
```

"Body" is the variable where we get the metadata and the data has to be put to storage blob named 123.json.

Using aws i use the command,

```
bucket.put_object(Key='source_metadata/'+str(call.sid)+'.json',Body=json.dumps(twilioMetadata))
```

Please guide on how to fix this issue. Thank you!

Comment: What is `twilioMetadata`? Is it a file where your code is running? Please make sure that the file is present.

Comment: twilioMetadata is a variable where there is json data

Comment: @RaphaelTitus, can you provide a sample of twilioMetadata?

Comment: Thanks Ivan!! Suggested code works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the `twilioMetadata` is the data itself or it's a path of the file.

Assume `twilioMetadata` is the data itself, then you can directly upload it to azure.

Here is the sample code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import json

#assume the variable is the data itself like below.
twilioMetadata ={1:'welcome',2:'to',3:'Geeks',4:'for',5:'Geeks'}

Body = json.dumps(twilioMetadata)

print(Body)

blob_service_client  = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("xxx")
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client("test5",blob="1234.json")


blob_client.upload_blob(Body)

print("**Completed**")
```

The test result:

[image]

Please let me know if you still have more issues:).